# Shower head pipe recessed: what do I need?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I'm nearing completion of a bathroom remodel and just need to install the fixtures. I have not had to install a brand new shower head before and am unsure of what I need to complete this project.

The pipe for the shower head is recessed into the wall, about flush with the inside of the wall.

What do I need in order to extend this pipe so I can attach my shower head? Thank you

Comment: Are you saying this is a copper pipe from the source, without any couplers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install a shower arm.

[image]

One end will (should) thread into the pipe in the wall, and the shower head will thread on to the other end.

Don't forget to use pipe dope/tape on the threads.

1. Apply tape/dope to the threads of the shower arm.
2. Thread the shower arm into the pipe in the wall (Do not over tighten).

   - If you have to use a wrench to tighten the arm. Wrap the arm with a towel/cloth, so the wrench does not mar the surface of the arm.
3. Slide the flange over the shower arm, so it covers the hole in the wall.
4. Apply tape/dope to the threads on the other end of the shower arm.
5. Thread the shower head on to the shower arm.